# How to know the ID of an Object when having just the"Object"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a very very beginner of JQuery and I'm trying to edit a JQuery image slider.

Relying on a variable inside the .js file, I'm able to retrieve the object on which the user pressed a key.

If I show in an "alert" the value of that variable I get `[object Object]`.

Now I have to know the id of that object? How canI do it.

Thank you

Comment: show your jquery code

Comment: object.id seems logical

Comment: DOM elements have IDs (accessible as `element.id`).   Other variables, most likely, don't.  Did you perhaps mean that you want to find the variable name that contains that object?

Comment: Thank everybody. I supposed I had to use object.id, but I thought I was wrong because I got "undefined". The reason was because the object I was getting, that I mixed up with another one,  hadn't an ID.
Anyway I solved the problem another way. Thank you again

Comment: @MDP please delete your question

Answer (score 0):

Your object is treated as a String when you put it in an alert.

```
var obj = {prop1: 'abc', prop2: 'def'};
alert(obj);
console.log(obj);
alert(obj.prop1);
```

Run the code above in chrome developer console. It will first alert [object Object], then "abc".

You can see the contents of your "object" in console log. You can then decide which of it's property is your "id".

Summary: Whenever you want to see the structure of your object, just do a console.log() on the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the object in the alert box using JSON.stringify() method.

```
alert(JSON.stringify( <your object> ))
```

Answer (score -1):

Generally speaking, you can get the HTML id of an HTML element this way:

```
$(element).attr('id');
```

Not sure if this is what you need. Would be great if you provided more info.

Comment: no, please, no.  If you have `element`, save yourself at least two function calls and just write `element.id` instead of `$(element).attr('id')`.  In any event I don't think the OP has an element, but some other JS object.

Comment: Yeah, right, your approach is faster and more concise. I agree, however this guy has mentioned he is just learning jQuery so it seems logical to me he wants to know the jQuery way.

Comment: the best way to use jQuery is to know when _not_ to use jQuery.  I'm 99% sure he doesn't have an element, anyway.

Comment: Thank everybody. I supposed I had to use object.id, but I thought I was wrong because I got "undefined". The reason was because the object I was getting, that I mixed up with another one, hadn't an ID. Anyway I solved the problem another way. Thank you again